# How to show data in gridview without textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a gridview in a web form application. I have provided the link below for reference. In this gridview, I have textboxes in each row and when I click save, it can save the data to database. However, the gridview itself still have the textboxes in each row after I click saved. My question is how can I not show the textboxes when I click the save button but instead only show the text that I have entered in each row? Help will be appreciated.

Here is the link that I use for my gridview

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-and-Retrieve-Dynamic-TextBox-values-in-GridView-to-SQL-Server-Database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use this Example below,for gridview CRUD opeartion with Editable textbox in columns,

[www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/select-add-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/select-add-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/)

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try :)

Comment: One more question, what if I put the label and the textbox in the same itemtemplate instead of the textbox in edittemplate and the label in item template, do I need to declare to txtTest.Visble = false and lblTEST.true behind the code when I click the button?

Answer (score 1):

In the markup of your page add a label to each itemtemplate column and set the visible property to false, like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>    
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then use FindControl like you are doing with the textboxes and set visible for the textboxes to false and visible for the labels to true in the click event of the Save button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, than I just need to add the <`%Bind %'> this text tag in the label field right?

Comment: From your link, it seems you are populating the textboxes in code behind. You can do the same for the labels. You only need to bind the labels to data if you are not populating them manually.

Comment: Do I need to declare the textbox visibility as false  and lable's visibility as true in order to only show the the label?

Comment: Yes you will need to do that.